# React: how to get Material UI's grid spacing to work?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI's Grid (https://material-ui.com/api/grid) for my layout, however while the columns and rows are working fine, the `spacing` attribute doesn't seem to work.

I have imported Grid as such: `import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'`

```
  <Grid container spacing={10}>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      CONTENT
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      CONTENT
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

But no padding appears.

Would anyone know how to I can include spacing in the grid?

Comment: The valid values for `spacing` are 0 to 10 (https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#grid-api). 16 is not a valid value.

Comment: @RyanCogswell oops that's a typo in my question. It's meant to be 10 (I still have the same issue)

Comment: @MeltingDog can you provide codepen demo for the issue?

Answer (score 15):

For me problem was I was not using item for Grid items.

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item xs={12}></Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12}></Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: same thing happened to me. Forgot to use the 'item' property. By adding them the spacing worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Just having Content inside the `<Grid>` wouldn't work, but if you put it in a `<div>` or a `<Paper>` you would get what you need...

relevant **js**:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  grid: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  },
  span: {
    border: "1px solid pink",
    backgroundColor: "lightpink`"
  },
  span2: {
    border: "1px solid green",
    backgroundColor: "lightgreen"
  },
  span3: {
    border: "1px solid blue",
    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
  },
}));

const App = () => {
  var classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Hello name="React" />
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <br />
      <Grid container spacing={10}>
        <Grid item xs className={classes.grid}>
          <div className={classes.span}>CONTENT</div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs className={classes.grid}>
          <div className={classes.span}>CONTENT</div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <hr />
      <Grid container spacing={8}>
        <Grid item xs className={classes.grid}>
          <div className={classes.span2}>CONTENT</div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs className={classes.grid}>
          <div className={classes.span2}>CONTENT</div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <hr />
      <Grid container spacing={6}>
        <Grid item xs className={classes.grid}>
          <div className={classes.span3}>CONTENT</div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs className={classes.grid}>
          <div className={classes.span3}>CONTENT</div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

example [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r6nfyt)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue when using the `sx` prop on the Grid components. Be sure to place any custom styling only on children of the Grid components.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My problem was also regarding this. I had accidentally applied a background color to the Grid element instead of the subcomponents. Because the spacing prop uses padding this led to the spacing being colored over.

Creating a Box/div container element for my subcomponents and applying the styling to this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Grid spacing is applied as padding, when your using the `xs or sm`, there padding will overide the top one, so you will get the top bottom padding

[image: Grid Padding]

Comment: This actually made me understand the problem. I just put my components inside of a <Box /> and solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

What would have made a lot more sence and removed the need for this question being asked is

```
<GridConatainer>
 <GridItem>
 </GridItem>
</GridContainer>
```

however they have opted for a harder to read and more confusing alternative:

```
<Grid container>
 <Grid item>
 </Grid>
</Grid>
```